# Sirius on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

How does one install the Sirius voice assistant on Ubuntu 14.10?
I would very much like to test it out,but apparently it needs compiling by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite full instructions in the "install" section of this page: http://sirius.clarity-lab.org/sirius/ It's quite an involved process, and too long to outline in full here. But they have simplified the installation somewhat with a series of bash scripts that automate much of it.

Comment: TL;DR: yes, you need to compile.